# copying executables to system/bin in android

Tags: android, android-build

I am building the android source code.
I added my custom defined code in `external/myservice` folder i changed the make file according to ping application.
I also added the path to myservice to `build/core/main.mk`. 
My problem is when the build is completed the executables that are generated are not copied in `system/bin` folder instead they go to `out/target/product/../obj/EXECUTABLES/myservice_intermediates/` folder.

What should i do so that my generated executables go directly to `out/target/product/../system/bin` folder.??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally i found the answer.

you have to add the executable or package or library name in PRODUCT_PACKAGES variable present in `device/../<device name>/<devicename>.mk` file as

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += <name of binary or apk or shared library>
```

The file will go to folder `system/bin or system/app or system/lib` as the case may be.